# Rendering error messages for form_tag that creates multiple objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure how to display the error messages for my form when using it in this `form_tag` scenario. My code below allows me to create 5 products at once on a form but unfortunately only renders the notice that "an error occurred...".

Here is my code:

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :name, :purchase_date, :product_store, :in_category
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store
  attr_reader :product_store
  validates_inclusion_of :in_category, :in => [true, false]
  validates_presence_of :name, :price, :store_id, :user_id
  validates_numericality_of :price

  def product_store=(id)
    self.store_id = id
  end
end
```

**Products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @products = Array.new(5) { Product.new }
  end

  def create_multiple
   @products = current_user.products.create(params[:products].map { |_k, p| p.merge params[:product] })
    if @products.each(&:save)
       redirect_to :back, :notice => "Success!"
    else
       redirect_to :back, :notice => "An error occured, please try again."
    end
  end
end
```

**Form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_products_path, :method => :post do %>
    <%= error_messages_for @product  %> 

       # the :purchase_date and :in_category are merged into all 5 Products.

            <%= date_select("product", "purchase_date")  %> 

            <%= label_tag :in_category, 'Add to Category?' %>
              <%= radio_button("product", :in_category, 1) %>
              <%= radio_button("product", :in_category, 0) %>

            <% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
               <%= fields_for "products[#{index}]", product do |p| %>
                   <%= render "fields", :f => p %>
               <% end %>
            <% end %>

       <%= submit_tag "Done" %>
<% end %>
```

Theirs 2 issues. 1. Getting the validations for the fields outside of the `fields_for` to show .2. And then the ones inside of the `fields_for`. How could I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been trying to do much the same thing, with this:

```
    <% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
      <% product.errors.full_messages.each do |value| %>
        <li><%= value %></li>
      <% end %>
```

However, this only shows errors for the *first* product with errors. You submit it, and if there is a subsequent product with errors, you are sent back to that page, and that next product with errors shows its errors, etc.

EDIT: Got it. It has to do with how I was validating. Instead of this:

```
if @products.all?(&:valid?)
```

do this:

```
@products.each(&:valid?) # run the validations
if @products.all? { |t| t.errors.empty? }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `@products.map(&:valid?).all?` be a bit cleaner? Unlike `@products.all?(&:valid?)` it'll validate all products and then check whether all of them are valid. The problem with `@products.all?(&:valid?)` is that it runs until the first invalid record.